# How to find the area of the triangles inside of a rectangle with a circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

this is my first post so hopefully someone can help me. I am given a square, say 10cm x 10cm. I then am given a circle inside it that touches the center of each line of the square, and I am given the radius of the circle (5cm). I have to find the area AND the perimeter of the blue shared sections. Does anyone know how to do this? Also sorry for the bad drawing I just thought it may make it easier to explain the question. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Since I don't have enough reputation to post the pic I put it on my Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byj8wv5m9HlyZHBKNUQ2Q2xLanM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I can't open your link to paste it in, even in GeoGebra.  Please post a jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

What is the diameter of the circle compared to the side of the square?

How do you find areas of circle and square separately?

Can you express the blue area in terms of the above two areas?

What is the perimeter of a circle called? Can you find it? Remember that when dealing with a complicated shape that includes straight edges and curves you need to consider them separately.

Comment: Well the diameter of the circle is the same as the length of the side of the square, and the radius is just half of that. I know that the area of the square- the  area of the circle is the area of the shaded region, I just don't know how to find the perimeter of it.

Comment: Ah OK, for each corner shape, remember that the two line segments are of equal length and add up to a quarter of the square's perimeter. The curve is just a quadrant arc, with perimeter one quarter the circumference of the circle.

Comment: Well maybe my drawing is bad but doesn't the blue technically go all the way around the circle? In which case wouldn't I just take the area of the rectangle minus the area of the circle?

Comment: That is correct for the area of all four blue corner parts.  To find one, divide by four. It depends on what exactly you're asked to find. My previous comment was about that perimeter. That's just one corner section so you multiply by 4 for the whole blue region but then you can just add the perimeters of circle and square together. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
 radius = $r$ = $5$ cm

So,the diameter $2r$ = $10$ cm

So, the are of the circle is = $\pi{r^2}$ = $\pi\times{5^2}$ = $25\pi$

And, the perimeter is = $2\pi{r}$ = $2\times{\pi}\times{5}$ = $10\pi$

The each side of the square = $a$ = $10$

So, the area of the square = $a^2$ = $10^2$ = $100$

Perimeter of the square = $4\times{a}$ = $4\times{10}$ = $40$

So the area of the blue region = Area of the square $-$ Area of the circle = ${100}-{25\pi}$

And for the calculation of perimeter see the image below:
[image]